# Can I extract different phonegap device sources to pursue as native apps?

Tags: cordova

I am developing an app that appears to be the typical use case for phonegap development. That is, the app can easily be developed as a responsive web app. However, I would like to have the peace of mind that if I decide to split into larger teams down the run, I will be able to extract the code for each device type (i.e.: Extract android source code, iphone source code, etc.) and then pursue development for each device as a native app, without having to rewrite each codebase.

Is this possible, say, after building each device code via phonegap ? Will this provide the source for each device or will I still be limited to js/html/css source ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will still be limited to js/html/css. Phonegap doesn't take your js/html/css and convert it to native source code(Java, objective-c etc.).

Phonegap just serves as a wrapper so that it looks like an app. Easy way to understand it is that a phonegap app is basically a website (or web app) running locally on the cellphone.